# Apache Flink to use S3 for backend state and checkpoints

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-flink, flink-streaming, checkpoint, checkpointing

#### Background

- I was planning to use S3 to store the Flink's checkpoints using the `FsStateBackend`. But somehow I was getting the following error.

**Error**

```
org.apache.flink.core.fs.UnsupportedFileSystemSchemeException: Could not find a file system implementation for scheme 's3'. The scheme is not directly supported by Flink and no Hadoop file system to support this scheme could be loaded.
```

**Flink version:** I am using Flink 1.10.0 version.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have found the solution for the above issue, so here I am listing it in steps that are required.

#### Steps

1. We need to add some configs in the `flink-conf.yaml` file which I have listed below.

```yml
state.backend: filesystem
state.checkpoints.dir: s3://s3-bucket/checkpoints/ #"s3://<your-bucket>/<endpoint>"
state.backend.fs.checkpointdir: s3://s3-bucket/checkpoints/ #"s3://<your-bucket>/<endpoint>"


s3.access-key: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX #your-access-key
s3.secret-key: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx #your-secret-key

s3.endpoint: http://127.0.0.1:9000 #your-endpoint-hostname (I have used Minio)
```

2. After completing the first step we need to copy the respective(`flink-s3-fs-hadoop-1.10.0.jar` and `flink-s3-fs-presto-1.10.0.jar`) JAR files from the opt directory to the plugins directory of your Flink.

   - **E.g:--> 1.** Copy `/flink-1.10.0/opt/flink-s3-fs-hadoop-1.10.0.jar` to `/flink-1.10.0/plugins/s3-fs-hadoop/flink-s3-fs-hadoop-1.10.0.jar` *// Recommended for StreamingFileSink*
     **2.** Copy `/flink-1.10.0/opt/flink-s3-fs-presto-1.10.0.jar` to `/flink-1.10.0/plugins/s3-fs-presto/flink-s3-fs-presto-1.10.0.jar` *//Recommended for checkpointing*
3. Add this in checkpointing code

```scala
env.setStateBackend(new FsStateBackend("s3://s3-bucket/checkpoints/"))
```

4. After completing all the above steps re-start the Flink if it is already running.

**Note:**

- If you are using both(`flink-s3-fs-hadoop` and `flink-s3-fs-presto`) in Flink then please use `s3p://` specificly for `flink-s3-fs-presto` and `s3a://` for `flink-s3-fs-hadoop` instead of `s3://`.
- For more details click [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.11/ops/filesystems/s3.html).

Comment: One more thing: it is recommended to use `flink-s3-fs-presto` for checkpointing, and not `flink-s3-fs-hadoop`. The hadoop S3 tries to imitate a real filesystem on top of S3, and as a consequence, it has high latency when creating files and it hits request rate limits quickly. This is because before writing a key, it checks to see if the "parent directory" exists, which can involve a bunch of expensive S3 HEAD requests (which have very low request rate limits).

Comment: Also, with Hadoop S3 you may come to a situation where you fail restore operations because it looks like a state file is not there (HEAD request leading to false caching in a S3 load balancer). Only after a while will the file be visible and only then will the restore succeed.

Comment: So i encountered with the same issue as you and did the steps you recommended but i got weird error message saying "Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot use the root directory for checkpoints" did you had it as well ?