# I encountered an error when use flink to insert data into a Apachi hudi table

Tags: apache-flink, apache-hudi

Environment:
Flink: 1.15.2
Hudi flink: hudi-flink1.15-bundle-0.12.0.jar

When I execute the statements：

```
Flink SQL> CREATE TABLE t1(
>   uuid VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY NOT ENFORCED,
>   name VARCHAR(10),
>   age INT,
>   ts TIMESTAMP(3),
>   `partition` VARCHAR(20)
> )
> PARTITIONED BY (`partition`)
> WITH (
>   'connector' = 'hudi',
>   'path' = 's3a://flink-hudi/t1'，
>   'table.type' = 'MERGE_ON_READ'
> );
[INFO] Execute statement succeed.

Flink SQL> INSERT INTO t1 VALUES ('id1','Danny',23,TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:01','par1');
[INFO] Submitting SQL update statement to the cluster...
[INFO] SQL update statement has been successfully submitted to the cluster:
Job ID: 77f98b6de7db94a52206b2a4f7961141
```

The hudi table t1 is created, but only contains meta data diretory .hoodie.

**And an Error occurs:**

org.apache.flink.runtime.JobException: Recovery is suppressed by NoRestartBackoffTimeStrategy
at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.ExecutionFailureHandler.handleFailure(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:138)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.ExecutionFailureHandler.getFailureHandlingResult(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:82)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.handleTaskFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:301)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.maybeHandleTaskFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:291)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.updateTaskExecutionStateInternal(DefaultScheduler.java:282)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerBase.updateTaskExecutionState(SchedulerBase.java:739)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerNG.updateTaskExecutionState(SchedulerNG.java:78)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster.updateTaskExecutionState(JobMaster.java:443)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor61.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.lambda$handleRpcInvocation$1(AkkaRpcActor.java:304)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.akka.ClassLoadingUtils.runWithContextClassLoader(ClassLoadingUtils.java:83)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcInvocation(AkkaRpcActor.java:302)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:217)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.FencedAkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(FencedAkkaRpcActor.java:78)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:163)
at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:24)
at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:20)
at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:123)
at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse$(PartialFunction.scala:122)
at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.applyOrElse(CaseStatements.scala:20)
at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:171)
at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:172)
at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:172)
at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:537)
at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:535)
at akka.actor.AbstractActor.aroundReceive(AbstractActor.scala:220)
at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:580)
at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:548)
at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:270)
at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:231)
at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:243)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
Caused by: org.apache.hudi.exception.HoodieException: Exception while scanning the checkpoint meta files under path: s3a://flink-hudi/t1/.hoodie/.aux/ckp_meta
at org.apache.hudi.sink.meta.CkpMetadata.load(CkpMetadata.java:169)
at org.apache.hudi.sink.meta.CkpMetadata.lastPendingInstant(CkpMetadata.java:175)
at org.apache.hudi.sink.common.AbstractStreamWriteFunction.lastPendingInstant(AbstractStreamWriteFunction.java:243)
at org.apache.hudi.sink.common.AbstractStreamWriteFunction.initializeState(AbstractStreamWriteFunction.java:151)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.util.functions.StreamingFunctionUtils.tryRestoreFunction(StreamingFunctionUtils.java:189)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.util.functions.StreamingFunctionUtils.restoreFunctionState(StreamingFunctionUtils.java:171)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractUdfStreamOperator.initializeState(AbstractUdfStreamOperator.java:94)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamOperatorStateHandler.initializeOperatorState(StreamOperatorStateHandler.java:122)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator.initializeState(AbstractStreamOperator.java:286)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.RegularOperatorChain.initializeStateAndOpenOperators(RegularOperatorChain.java:106)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.restoreGates(StreamTask.java:700)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTaskActionExecutor$1.call(StreamTaskActionExecutor.java:55)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.restoreInternal(StreamTask.java:676)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.restore(StreamTask.java:643)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.runWithSystemExitMonitoring(Task.java:948)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.restoreAndInvoke(Task.java:917)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:741)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:563)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory: s3a://flink-hudi/t1/.hoodie/.aux/ckp_meta
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.s3GetFileStatus(S3AFileSystem.java:2344)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.innerGetFileStatus(S3AFileSystem.java:2226)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.getFileStatus(S3AFileSystem.java:2160)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.innerListStatus(S3AFileSystem.java:1961)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.lambda$listStatus$9(S3AFileSystem.java:1940)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.Invoker.once(Invoker.java:109)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.listStatus(S3AFileSystem.java:1940)
at org.apache.hudi.common.fs.HoodieWrapperFileSystem.lambda$listStatus$15(HoodieWrapperFileSystem.java:365)
at org.apache.hudi.common.fs.HoodieWrapperFileSystem.executeFuncWithTimeMetrics(HoodieWrapperFileSystem.java:106)
at org.apache.hudi.common.fs.HoodieWrapperFileSystem.listStatus(HoodieWrapperFileSystem.java:364)
at org.apache.hudi.sink.meta.CkpMetadata.scanCkpMetadata(CkpMetadata.java:216)
at org.apache.hudi.sink.meta.CkpMetadata.load(CkpMetadata.java:167)
... 18 more

expect insert data to hudi table successfully.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Flink job is trying to restore from state, but Hudi encounters an error caused by `No such file or directory: s3a://flink-hudi/t1/.hoodie/.aux/ckp_meta`. Since you confirmed the bucket was clean when you started, the best suggestion I can provide is to use the `s3p:///` filesystem, which forces Flink to use the Presto implementation (versus the Hadoop version). See [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64226597/apache-flink-to-use-s3-for-backend-state-and-checkpoints/64226598#comment113580451_64226598) as to why using the Hadoop filesystem could lead to a "file not found" situation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
After creating the bucket, I didn't do any manipulation except executing the SQL statements.

Comment: I've updated my answer based on your response